# San Francisco 311 Open Data, what does "mobile" mean under the category "cases by channel"?

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I'm checking out the San Francisco 311 Open Data (https://sf311.org/information/reports), but wanted to know what does "mobile" mean under the category "cases by channel"?

SMS Text? Whatsapp? Call? App?

Comment: Can you improve your question: that site is not about 'open data', it is about some sort of reports (which ones?). Describe the data, take a screenshot and insert it here. We should not have to go there to understand what you're writing about.

Comment: have you asked the san francisco digital team?